# Laravel: Products,Categories and SubCategories! (Relation ships)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem! I make something but, not work so i will ask u for help! So the problem is

I have this tables

```
products:
  name,subcategory_id,category_id,price,description
Categories:
  name,slug,timestamps
SubCategories:
  name,slug,timestamps
```

I want to make when smo call this url `/category/{category}/{subcategory}`
to get all products of subcategory are called! But when product don't have sub category to open only category , i mean `/category/{category}`

Thanks guys!

Comment: So you're asking for us to help you write your controllers, routes, and models?  Far too broad, give laravel.com/docs a go, they are very detailed.

Comment: No bro, i have Controller model and routes! I just want to help me with relationships

Comment: Then why are you asking about urls?

Comment: i just give examples!

Comment: Well, your first issue is you don't have any column relating subcategories to categories, but your question still seems to show you haven't made an effort reviewing the docs and attempting the relationships yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here i may help u with this!

First , you can use only one table for categories and subcategory!

You can make this:

```
 |---------------------------------------
 |id| |parent_id|    |name|       |slug|
 |1 | | (NULL)  | Electronics | electronics
 |2 | | 1       | Phones      | phones
```

Now category electronic have children `Phones`

So in your `Category.php` model u can make that

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
*/
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id','id');
}
```

Now u can use foreach to display your children and category! Hope that helpful! ;)

Comment: How retrieve Subcategory of subcategory. In this case I can get only one level of subcategory...

Comment: @AlejandroBeltran you can do something like this Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get();

Answer (score 1):

It's classic problem related with databases You should use hierarchical child/parent relation. At first Your design of database is bad, just add one column with root category which has "0" in PARENT_ID.

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES ( 
      CATEGORY_ID  NUMBER,
      PARENT_ID    NUMBER,
      NAME         VARCHAR(255), 
      CREATE_TS    TIMESTAMP(0));
```

and then read this : 
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
&
[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)
&
Bear in mind that You are mixing logic of GUI with SQL role. If You want to return in single query     then Your presentation layer will be quite ugly ;-)

and also think about leaving just category_id in product table, if You have only 2 or 3 levels You don't need to point to subcategory and category.